# SKIP reading first 150 row from flat file

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I did lookup old posts but this does not seem to be working.......I want to basically skip reading first 150 rows....

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(FileInfo.FullName)) 
{ 
    string line; 
    while(!stream.EndOfStream) 
    { 
        for (int i = 1; i >= 150; i++) 
        { 
            line = stream.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    }  
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your loop is a bit strange, the >=150 won't happen so you'll only run once. Should probably be <=150.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(FileInfo.FullName)) 
{ 
    string line; 
    int i = 0;
    while(!stream.EndOfStream) 
    { 
         i++;
         line = stream.ReadLine();
         if ( i <= 150 ) continue;

         // Do something with the line. 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running your loop that tries to read 150 lines until you reach the end of the stream, and you have your condition reversed, it should be <= 150 , so you don't actually read any lines.

```
bool SkipLines(StreamReader reader, int line_cnt) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < line_cnt; i++) {
      String line = stream.ReadLine(); 
      if(line == null) {
         return false;
   }
  return true;
}
```

And call it as e.g.

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(FileInfo.FullName)) {
   if(!SkipLines(stream, 150)) {
      return; //or do whatever you need to if when the file contained less
              //than 150 lines

 ... process rest of file
}
```

Comment: This will die if less than 150 lines

Comment: @Darthg8r ReadLine() returns null in that case, which is handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about loading the entire file into memory the simplest way is probably just to do this:

```
var theRest = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(150).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(FileInfo.FullName)) 
{ 
    string line; 
    int i = 0;
    while(!stream.EndOfStream && (i++ <= 150)) 
    { 
         line = stream.ReadLine();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to read row by row from .BIN file.if u want to read only first 150 rows  by changing the condition in the while loop.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string line;
                int i = 0;

                while (!stream.EndOfStream && (i++ >= 0))//for neglecting first 150 rows the condition will be (i++ <= 150) try this.I hope it helps.
                {
                    line = stream.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```